# Find minimum value in 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I want to make a generic method which returns the minimum value of a two dimensional array.I am going by the following code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T Max(T[][]stuff) {
    T min = stuff[0][0];
    for (T[] row : stuff) {
        for (T elt : row) {
            if (elt.compareTo(min) > 0) {
                max = elt;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

But in stead of max, I need to find min and I have to use the signature:

```
public static E Min<E>(E[,] matrix) where E : IComparable<E>
```

Sorry if this sounds like homework but I just can't wrap my head around it. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Provide a `BinaryOperator<T>` as a parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner How would this look in code? I'm new to this.

Comment: `BinaryOperator<T> op` as a parameter; then `max = op.apply(max, elt);` instead of the innermost conditional.

Comment: `<E>` after an identifier declaration, `[,]` and `where` are not standard Java. What language is this for?

Comment: I believe it is written in c# but I have to code it in Java, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T min(T[][]stuff) {
    T min = stuff[0][0];
    for (T[] row : stuff) {
        for (T elt : row) {
            if (elt.compareTo(min) < 0)
                min = elt;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach:

```
Optional<T> min = Arrays.stream(stuff)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .min(Comparable::compareTo);
```